# I am quite unsure of how echo command works in the following two scenarios

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, echo

I have tried fiddling with echo command to to add `$_GET` to a text file but looks like it does not work but escaping it with `\` works may be because `$` is special character in bash.

For example, `echo "\$_GET" >> newfile.txt` works.

[image: Screenshot showing the weird echo behavior to me]

What I wanted to ask is how does `echo` work in each of the following two cases in the given screenshot. The second functionality of `echo` is what I am not able to grasp.

Comment: In the second case, `$_` *"expands to the last argument to the previous command, after expansion"* - see `man bash` under `Special Parameters`

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting. https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 2):

`$_` is a special variable in bash and it represents the last argument of previous command executed. You executed

```
cat get.txt
```

and then

```
echo "$_" >> dollar.txt
```

It is obvious that `get.txt` was the last argument of previous command (`cat`).